# Add Audio to video with existing audio using FFmpeg and change volume of of both audios

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

Add  Audio to video with existing audio using FFmpeg and change volume of both audios

I am using this command from ffmpeg to merge audio to video

video.mp4 has `video and audio`, and audio.m4a only has `audio`

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.m4a -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy -shortest output.mp4`

I want to merge audio to video but maintain audio from both video and the new audio file

I also want to change the volume of audio file that I want to add from current file to 1.5 times

and change the audio from the video file to 0.5 times

how can we change the volume and still maintain new and old audio in the merged file

Comment: Show the output of  `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.m4a`

Comment: I am able to merge the audio to video but how can i change the volume of video and the audio file during merging them